# Paint refresh code flickering when refreshed

Tags: c#, flicker

my code for my game had a paint system where is draws then redraws a car (or a box) every 50 ticks. i have really bad flickering when running the code (even when not moving) anything else you need i can grab :)

i have tried: 
-Double buffering
-Putting everything into a panel and refreshing that

//My Paint Code

```
            Bitmap greenCar = new 



            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(car.getDrawingbrushColor(), 
            car.getCarposition());
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(greenCar,car2.getCarposition());

    }
```

my timer code

```
        scoreTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick2);

        scoreTimer.Interval = 100;

        scoreTimer.Start();

        DoubleBuffered = true;
```

My Refresh Code

```
    {

        this.Counter.Text = Scorecounter.ToString();

        Scorecounter += 1;

        panel1.Refresh();

    }
```

i just dont want it to flicker, i is really holding me back.

Comment: Why are you hiding code from us?  What are those methods?  Post all the code that duplicates the problem for us for we can reproduce it.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Windows Forms?